# RamdaJs with typescript, avoid errors when point free

Tags: typescript, ramda.js, pointfree

```
const getColumnsBySection = R.pipe(
    R.filter(c => c.section != null),
    R.groupBy(c => c.section)
  );
```

When using point free with RamdaJs as in this function. I get typescript errors

```
 Type 'Dictionary<unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'readonly unknown[]': length, concat, join, slice, and 18 more.
TS2339: Property 'section' does not exist on type 'unknown'
```

How are you suppose to use point free functions without getting typescript errors like these?

Comment: There is nothing to define a type anywhere, and so no type can be inferred... What seqence is passing though this pipe? I.e. What type is `c` in your predicates and selectors? If the pipe function is well written/typed (I've never used ramda), you should only need to provide this typing for `c` in the predicate for `filter`, and type should "flow" from there. What is a `Dictionary<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either cast the function to the types you expect, or you can lean more on the ramda library with a construction like this instead:

```js
const { anyPass, complement, pipe, propSatisfies, filter, groupBy, prop, isNil, isEmpty } = R

const isBlank = anyPass([isNil, isEmpty]);

const isPresent = complement(isBlank);

const getColumnsBySection = pipe(
  filter(propSatisfies(isPresent, 'section')),
  groupBy(prop('section'))
);

const samples = [
  {section: 'trees', name: 'birch'}, 
  {section: 'vines', name: 'grape'},
  {section: 'trees', name: 'cedar'},
  {section: 'vines', name: 'ivy'},
];

const results = getColumnsBySection(samples);
console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```
import * as R from "ramda"

interface Monkey{
  name:string;
}

const p = R.pipe(
  (m: Monkey) => `cheeky-${m.name}`, // `m` can't be inferred, hence type annotation
  (s) => `hello ${s}` // here `s` *can* be inferred
)

console.log(p({name:"monkey"}))
```

If we take away the `Monkey` typing from the first composed function, Typescript can't possibly know that the `m` argument being passed to it has a `name` property and therefore can't correctly type the arguments of the resulting function `p`.

However, for subsequent functions passed to `pipe`, due to the typings in `@types/ramda`, `R.pipe` is able to correctly infer the typing of these  composed functions from the return-type of the previous function in the argument list.

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-tdd-nl3qt?file=/src/index.ts)